# How can I provide Specflow to execute the same scenario multiple times?

Tags: selenium, specflow, specrun

With SpeFlow+SpecRun every faild test Case will be executed three times.
And if one of this executions is Failed the Scenario will be Failed despite it is Passed.

There's is any configuration to do it to provide this mode of execution.
And The problem that specflow create a report for each execution?
So Please some help.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with the creation of the report each execution? Could you be a little more precise?

Comment: We found report for each execution, but really w need just one report for each test case and not for each execution.

Comment: Ok, so you want that for each test a separate report and file is generated?

Comment: Not a seperate file but just one report for each test case(scenario) not more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the retry of a scenario, you have to set the retryCount parameter in the execution element to 0.
See http://www.specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Profiles/#Execution

Comment: But where can I found this parameter ? and what's the problem with my solution it work.

Answer (score 1):

See below to handle retry count:

```
<Execution stopAfterFailures="0" testThreadCount="1" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" retryCount="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution That I find is to change the parameter **stopAfterFailures** to 1 (the previous value is 3) in the file Default.srprofile.

```
<Execution stopAfterFailures="1" testThreadCount="1" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" />
```